# Modify Django user delete method?

Tags: django, django-models, overriding, django-users

If I go to the Django admin page and delete a user, I want it to run some code before/after it deletes the user. I know about overriding models' `delete()` methods, but I'm not sure how to apply it to  a built-in model. Also, I'd like to be able to do it without 'subclassing' the `User` model and creating a (for instance) `MyUser` model.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can listen to the django pre_delete and post_delete signal:
here is the doc link:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_delete
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_delete